# Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания:

*Я не мог и до сих пор не могу понять.*

Answer (score 2):

Предложение незаконченное, но в Нацкорпусе есть похожие по структуре предложения:  http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E5+%EC%EE%E3+%E8+%ED%E5+%EC%EE%E3%F3

На это, ощупывая в жилетном кармане золотые кружки, я **не мог и не могу** дать положительного ответа. [А. С. Грин. Фанданго (1927)]

Город без меня я могу себе представить, но себя без города ― Ленинграда ― я представить себе **не мог (и не могу)**. [Вадим Шефнер. Листопад воспоминаний (1945-1955) //

Answer (score 1):

Два приемлемых варианта:

Без знаков препинания - "Я не мог и до сих пор не могу понять".

Со скобками - "Я не мог (и до сих пор не могу) понять".